# Часы показывают серверное время, но на аяксе с одним запросом

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php, база-данных

Как можно сделать или может кто видел исходники готового решения.
Ситуация следующая, на сайте показывается серверное время 
Московское время:**<?=date("H")?>** **:** **<?=date("i");?>**

Как можно сделать это на аяксе, следующим образом. Пользователь заходит на страницу, идет запрос для показа времени, и больше запроса нет. Дальше яваскрипт сам прибавляет секунды и меняет время?

Comment: а что именно у вас не получается?

Логика простая, 
$.post(URL, function(data){
   var time=data
});

далее setTimeOut(); прибавляет +1 к секундам каждые 1000мс и формируем часы.

Comment: вы не могли бы более полно написать? я не знаток js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуемся примермо [[[[@DemoS](/users/2880/demos)](/users/2880/demos)](/users/2880/demos)](/users/2880/demos)

На сервере должен быть скрипт посылаемый серверное время:

time.php:

```
<?php
  $servTime=Array();
  //$this_time=time();
  $servTime['currentYear']=date("Y");
  $servTime['currentMonth']=date("n");
  $servTime['currentDate']=date("j");
  $servTime['currentDay']=date("N");
  $servTime['currentHours']=date("G");
  $servTime['currentMinutes']=date("i");
  $servTime['currentSeconds']=date("s");
  echo encode_json($servTime);
?>
```

Далее используем функции [[[[@DemoS](/users/2880/demos)](/users/2880/demos)](/users/2880/demos)](/users/2880/demos) нужно переделат так, чтобы они каждую секунду не обращались к серверу, а приплюсовав 1 к секундам формировала и минуты и часы (тут самим придеться додумывать).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var objTime;
   $.getJSON("time.php", function(data){
     objTime=$.parseJSON(data);
   });
});
```

objTime  - будет объектом "время". objTime.currentYear - будет соответствовать году итд.

Далее передаем объект  objTime функции clock();

Answer (score 2):

Вот моя реализация, только идет сразу время клиента, но подточить, думаю, не проблема:
[дата и время (jQuery)](http://ru-info.net/index.php?page=post&id=1).

Answer (score 1):

Если не крайне важна абсолютная точность то можно сделать намного проще:

```
 

    var serverDate;
    function timeStart() {
        timestamp = document.getElementById("moscowTime").innerHTML;
        serverDate = parseInt(timestamp) * 1000;
        setInterval("showTime()",1000);
    }
    function showTime() {
        serverDate = serverDate + 1000;
        date = new Date(serverDate);
        var time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
        var timeWrapper = document.getElementById("moscowTime");
        timeWrapper.innerHTML = time;
    }
    onload = function() {
        timeStart();
    }
<div id="moscowTime"><?=time();?></div>
```

PS:написано без аякса т.к. выложил строго алгоритм, конечно точность будет выше если брать timestamp аяксом на онлоаде.