# Живые часы на JavaScript

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Приведите, пожалуйста пример `JavaScript` кода, который бы показывал текущее время на сервере.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, скажем, что-то типа того:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
seconds = 0;
minutes = 0;
hours = 0;
function update_clock(){
$.post('gettime.php',function(data){
  data = eval('('+data+')');
  seconds = data.s;
  minutes = data.m;
  hours = data.h;
  updateDiv(hours,minutes,seconds);
});
}

function serverclock(){
  seconds++;
  if(seconds==60){
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if(minutes==60){
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
      if(hours==24){
        hours = 0;
      }
    }
    if(minutes%10==0){
      update_clock();//Это функция, которая описана в самом верху.
    }
  }
  updateDiv(hours,minutes,seconds);
}

function updateDiv(hours,minutes,seconds){
    $('#timediv').html(zeroPad(hours,2)+":"+zeroPad(minutes,2)+":"+zeroPad(seconds,2));
}

function zeroPad(num,count){ 
var numZeropad = num + '';
while(numZeropad.length < count) {
numZeropad = "0" + numZeropad; 
}
return numZeropad;
}
update_clock();
setInterval('serverclock()',1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="timediv"></div>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
print(date('{\h:H,\m:i,\s:s}'));
?>
```

Comment: Не получается :-( 
Наверное я что-то делаю не так... Ну все равно спасибо за совет.

Comment: Что именно не получается? Ссылку киньте. Скорее всего(линг меня уже неоднократно тыкал в это носом) идет конфликт переменных и надо это сделать замыканием.

Comment: Сейчас, например, вообще ничего не выводит. Даже стоящие часы. Ссылку кинуть не могу - проект на локальном компьютере. Все файлы (index.php, gettime.php, jquery.js)как в ответе сделал.

Comment: [knes.ru/liveclock][1]
[FILES - Zip][2]


  [1]:http://knes.ru/liveclock/
  [2]:http://knes.ru/liveclock/liveclock.zip

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Или если все же Вы перепутали "сервер" с "клиентом":

```
alert(new Date().toString());
```

Comment: Нет, я не перепутал. Именно на сервере :-)

Comment: Ну тогда аяксом (как вариант).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам будет интересно почитать [Часы показывают серверное время, но на аяксе с одним запросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26299/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#34500)